# How to create a pop up picture slide with a different set of pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am creating a table in html that shows products and different information. When the user clicks on the product photo in one cell of the table, i want it to open up a picture slider that contains different pictures of that product (those picture urls are saved in their each array) I tried using fancybox but the effect isn't what I am looking for. All the examples of fancybox has all the pictures already on the page, and uses a pop up picture slider to just cycle through them all. I have my code set up like:

```
<!-- FANCYBOX LINKS NOT INCLUDED IN EXAMPLE -->
      <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    closeBtn  : false,
                    arrows    : false,
                    nextClick : true,

                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width  : 50,
                            height : 50
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            function displayPics(aPics){
                //the pop up carousel slider for more pictures

            }

            // add pictures as they come
            var CT4by6 = [
                'images/cargotrailers/4x6/4x6-1.jpg',
            ];

             var CT5by8 = [
                'images/cargotrailers/5x8/5x8-1.jpg',
            ];


            function showPics(imgNum){
                switch (imgNum){
                    case 'img1':
                        // pass to function that displays sliders
                        displayPics(CT4by6);
                        break;

                    case 'img2':
                        // pass to function that displays sliders
                        displayPics(CT5by8);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        </script>
```

HTML:

```
             <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Trailer Model</th>
                            <th>Unit Number</th>
                            <th>Daily Price</th>
                            <th>Weekend Only*</th>
                            <th>Weekly**</th>
                            <th>Monthly**</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Image -->
                                <img src="images/cargotrailers/4x6.jpg" id="img1" onclick="showPics('img1')" />
                            </td>
                       </tr>
                </table>
```

I am sort of stuck at the point where I can pass the array of picture urls when the appropriate picture is clicked, but this isn't how fancybox works, to my knowledge. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that

```
$(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
    // API options
});
```

...binds any element (normally an anchor `<a>` tag) to fancybox, so pretty much those elements should previously exist on the page as you mentioned.

You still can have each group of images on its own *array* and open them in fancybox programmatically using the `$.fancybox.open()` method.

But first, you need to modify your HTML in order to pass the name of the *array*, from where fancybox will take the *gallery* elements. For this you could use (HTML5) `data` attributes like :

```
<img class="img" data-href="CT4by6" src="images/cargotrailers/4x6.jpg" />
<img class="img" data-href="CT5by8" src="images/cargotrailers/5x8.jpg" />
....etc.
```

**Notice** we removed the `ID` and `onclick` *attributes* and we set a `class` and the `data` *attributes* instead.

Then we can bind a `click` event to the (*class*) `.img` selector to call the `$.fancybox.open()` method programmatically like :

```
$(".img").on("click", function(){
    $.fancybox.open(window[$(this).data("href")],{
        // API options
    }); // fancybox
}); // click
```

Notice we used `window[$(this).data("href")]` to access the (globally defined) *array* by its name.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**